# Flatten object properties in Flow

Tags: flowtype

I have a seemingly simple question about [Flow](https://flow.org/).

Given the following objects:

```
const input: InputObject = {
  key1: {
    prop1: 'value1',
  },
  key2: {
    prop2: 'value2',
    prop3: false,
  },
};

const output: OutputObject = {
  prop1: 'value1',
  prop2: 'value2',
  prop3: false,
};
```

How can I get the type of `OutputObject`, based on `InputObject`?

```
type OutputObject = ??magic?? InputObject ??magic??;
```

### Context

I want to type a React HOC component which will inject some properties *based on a configuration object*, like:

```
type Props = {
  prop1: string,
  prop2: string,
  prop3: boolean,
};

class Component extends React.Component<Props> { /* */ }

Hoc({
  key1: () => ({
    prop1: 'value1',
  }),
  key2: () => ({
    prop2: 'value2',
    prop3: false,
  }),
})(Component);
```

I already know how to correctly type the HOC to get it type-safe and how to get `InputObject` from the configuration object passed to the HOC, but I'm stuck at how to "flatten" the `InputObject` type to `OutputObject` type, so that `<Component />` will be happy because it will be getting all the required properties from the HOC :)

Even more important! I want the following to be a type error:

```
const HocComponent = Hoc({
  key1: () => ({
    prop1: 'value1',
  }),
  key2: () => ({
    prop2: 'value2',
  }),
})(Component);

<HocComponent />              // Error! prop3 is required
<HocComponent prop3={true} /> // Happy again
```

Thank you!

Comment: And `InputObject` could have arbitrary number of child objects, not just `key1` and `key2`?

Comment: I'm certain that this can't be done. But perhaps you could give more context on why you want to do it, and there might be a different solution?

Comment: I agree that knowing your goal, as well as providing a more concrete example would help. However, You can try [`$Call<F>`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-call)